# How to make sure the GPG's home directory is safe?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg

I am a novice with cryptography. I am studying the GPG for encryption of my backup files.

My current understanding is that the keys are saved in the home directory of GPG. And it means that if someone can access my home directory, all of my encryption efforts would be in vain as he can decrypt my backup files with the stolen key.

But then, the GPG has to use the home directory and it seems the risk is unavoidable. (the risk of someone accessing my computer secretly and copy the home directory.)

Am I understanding the matter in the right way? If so, how can I protect my home directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your private key is usually encrypted, with a key derived from a passphrase (this is the passphrase you need to enter any time you want to decrypt or sign a message). The key generation from the passphrase isn't the greatest (it's an old algorithm) so you need to use a really good passphrase if you're worried about the key being stolen. You'll probably want to revoke any key that might be stolen anyhow, as quickly as possible.

With that said: GPG doesn't actually have to store the keyring in your home directory. That's the default, but you can specify an alternate location when running the program or in the config file (see the `--keyring`. `--no-default-keyring`, `--secret-keyring`, and `--primary-keyring` options in the manual). You can also just replace the GPG files with symbolic links to files elsewhere, for example on a flashdrive; then only insert the drive (or otherwise make the files available) when you intend to use them. Symlinks only need to be valid while in use; the rest of the time they can point to a non-existent path.

For that matter, GPG has the ability to store keys on a hardware security module. This is almost certainly the most secure option. There are various models available, most of which are either designed for permanent installation in a computer or connect via USB (some, like smart cards, require a special reader). A common - but not the only - choice for a USB removable security module are the various generations of Yubikey, which can [store your GPG keys](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013790259-Using-Your-YubiKey-with-OpenPGP) more securely than putting them on a simple flashdrive, and you can make GPG use those keys.

Finally, though, consider your threat model. If you're worried about a program that might have read access to your home directory, it must be either running as you or as super-user (root/Administrator) and either way it has other ways to compromise you. It could alter your PATH environment variable so that the "gpg" program points to a malicious script that steals your passphrase, and possibly also the contents of every encrypted message, in addition to your key files. There are other, potentially less-obvious, ways that it could steal the secrets too. The point being, once something malicious on your PC can read your ~/.gnupg directory, you have bigger problems than whether it can just read the files therein and whether your passphrase is good enough. If your threat model includes offline attacks - somebody stealing your whole PC and removing its hard disk, for example - then encryption is your best protection (after as much physical security as is practical), and rather than rely exclusively on the private key's passphrase, you should just encrypt the whole /home directory and possibly everything except the boot partition, with a strong passphrase and/or additional protections such as USB devices, TPM, etc.

Comment: One should always check with `which gpg` before run.

Comment: @kelalaka that's useless, an attacker might have replaced `which` as well to make sure its `gpg` hook remains hidden. If an attacker has code execution on your machine as your user, it's game over. There's nothing you can do

Comment: @ShellCode so, one should then always check the which, then one should always check the bash, then... Step by step, until you make sure that there is no compromise.

Comment: Yeah sure, every time you want to use gpg you should buy a brand new PC, flash the firmware of the motherboard, download Linux source code, audit it, compile it, download gpg source code, audit it, compile it, and THEN you can use gpg (don't forget to audit the code of the compiler itself). Of course repeat the process every time you have to use gpg, you might have been compromised since last time you used it. --- `until you make sure that there is no compromise` : you can't, that's my point. You have to trust your setup at some point.

Comment: @ShellCode You forgot to audit the compiler https://stackoverflow.com/a/66303820/1820553 :)